# How to select specific item of gallery programmatically?

Tags: android, scroll, gallery

I have an android gallery and I have 100 items (10 of them visible).
But my question is how to select some specific item programmatically ?

Let say I have a button and when clicked I want the gallery item number 55 to be selected. (to be in focus)

How can I do this ? is it possible at all

I saw that there is method in gallery that is called scrollTo(x,y) but it is in pixels and doesn't fit my needs.

Any ides ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
gallery.setSelection(position);
```

or

```
gallery.setSelection(position, animate)
```

if you want to animate to that position.

Answer (score 0):

regrarding details for the thumbnails in the Gallery app...

an older version of CacheService is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Gallery3D/com/cooliris/cache/CacheService.java.htm)

see methods ( buildThumbs, queryThumbs ... ) for hints on using attr list for the thumb objects... You may be able to select your object using some public method. You would have to relate this info to the api for the newer versions of gallery app.